# Why am i having problem with my toggle button

Tags: flutter, dart, dart-null-safety

Hello guys I am total new to flutter so I was trying to build a BMI calculator , so i was trying to create a toggle switch between "MALE" and "FEMALE", so that when one card is clicked the other becomes inactive and i was trying to use a ternary code to achieve that

but the problem is if i run the app on my emulator and if i click on the "MALE" part it doesn't get selected but if i click on the "FEMALE" part the "MALE" card get selected and the "FEMALE card remain inactive and the "MALE" card still remains active unless i reload the app but it doesnt solve the problem.

so please if someone can show me on how to fix that error. i will be happy for that
[image]

```
 enum Gender {
  male,
  female,
  empty,
}
class ReuseableCard extends StatelessWidget {
  ReuseableCard({required this.colour, this.cardChild, this.onPress});
  final Color colour;
  final Widget? cardChild;
  final VoidCallback? onPress;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GestureDetector(
      onTap: onPress,
      child: Container(
          child: cardChild,
          margin: EdgeInsets.all(15),
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
              color: colour, borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15))),
    );
  }
}

class _InputPageState extends State<InputPage> {
  Gender selectedGender = Gender.empty;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Center(child: Text('BMI CALCULATOR')),
      ),
      body: Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
        children: [
          Expanded(
              child: Row(
            children: [
              Expanded(
                child: ReuseableCard(
                  cardChild: cardTitle(
                    fontIcon: FontAwesomeIcons.mars,
                    cardText: 'MALE',
                  ),
               //I DONT KNOW IF I AM WRONG HERE
                  colour: selectedGender == Gender.male
                      ? activeCardColor
                      : inactiveCardColor,
                ),
              ),
              Expanded(
                child: ReuseableCard(
                  onPress: () {
                    setState(() {
                      selectedGender = Gender.male;
                    });
                  },
                  cardChild: cardTitle(
                    fontIcon: FontAwesomeIcons.venus,
                    cardText: 'FEMALE',
                  ),
                  //I DONT KNOW IF I AM WRONG HERE
                  colour: selectedGender == Gender.female
                      ? activeCardColor
                      : inactiveCardColor,
                ),
              )
            ],
          )),
          Expanded(
            child: ReuseableCard(
              onPress: () {
                selectedGender = Gender.female;
              },
              colour: activeCardColor,
              cardChild: Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: [
                  Text(
                    'HEIGHT',
                    style: labelTextStyle,
                  ),
                  Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.baseline,
                    textBaseline: TextBaseline.alphabetic,
                    children: [
                      Text(
                        height.toString(),
                        style: numberStyle,
                      ),
                      Text('cm'),
                    ],
                  ),
                  SliderTheme(
                    data: SliderTheme.of(context).copyWith(
                        inactiveTrackColor: Color(0xFF8D8E98),
                        thumbColor: Color(0xFFEB1555),
                        overlayColor: Color(0x29EB1555),
                        activeTrackColor: Colors.white,
                        thumbShape:
                            RoundSliderThumbShape(enabledThumbRadius: 20.0),
                        overlayShape:
                            RoundSliderOverlayShape(overlayRadius: 30.0)),
                    child: Slider(
                      value: height.toDouble(),
                      min: 120.0,
                      max: 220.0,
                      onChanged: (double newValue) {
                        setState(() {
                          height = newValue.round();
                        });
                      },
                    ),
                  ),
            ],
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can see that your male box does not have method `onPress` so it will not do anything and your female box `onPress` set the value to `male` so that clicking female box will make male active and does nothing to female box and for some reason your `height` box sets value to `female`.

you need to move the `onPress` methods one level up ⬆️

the one on female box move it to -> male box

the one on height box move it to -> female box

and this should fix the issue.

Comment: can you take a look at the  second screenshot i uploaded @to-be it still doesn't change simultaneously

Comment: Why are setting value of `selectedGender` to female on clicking male box and the same for the other one?

Comment: Can you take a look at the code again on female on press the value is now set to `selectedGender=Gender.male` while on male box `SelectedGender=Gender.male`
isnt? in the on press function but it still doesnt change simultaneously?
where did i go wrong please? i have reuploaded the image again

Comment: The male card should set `selectedGender` to `Gender.male` and the female card should set `selectedGender` to `Gender.female`. Be sure to set the value inside of `setState(() {...})`.

Answer (score 0):

Yemi from the screenshot you posted make the following changes to the female card...

```
// from this
onPress: (){
selectedGender = Gender.male;
}

// to this
onPress: (){
setState((){
selectedGender = Gender.female;
});
}
```

And I would suggest that you take your time and rewatch the module from the tutorial you are watching - I assume you are following Angela yu's course. Plus if you feel stressed out just take a break and come back to it later

Comment: i noticed something about this after i changed the code as you suggested,  after i hot restart the app, if i click on the "MALE" box it get selected. but if i click on the "FEMALE" box it doesn't get selected instantly unless i adjust slider is it normal?

Answer (score 0):

add this line inside male **onPress**

```
setState((){
    selectedGender = Gender.male;
})
```

and add this line inside famele **onPress**

```
setState((){
   selectedGender = Gender.female;
})
```

It will be resolve your issue.

Comment: Thanks I just saw my mistake its now working fine